# vb.net Datagridview CheckBox column

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have a Datagridview with CheckBox column, I want to unable to check the checkbox of if the stock is 0 and Messagbox that the stock is 0

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellEndEdit
        Dim selected As String = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("checkbox").Value

        If dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("checkbox").Value = True Then
            If dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value <= 0 Then   'cell9 item stock
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("checkbox").Value = False
                MsgBox("Invalid Stocks is 0")
            End If
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Seems like a little debugging is required.  First off, notice you're executing this code in the CellEndEdit event.  Are you sure this is firing when you expect.  Next are you getting expected values for selected?  Also notice you're chopping and changing datatypes, suggest reading up on `Set Option Strict On` which helps avoid un-intended type castings as I suspect you have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cell to ReadOnly first then change its value.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).Value = 0 Then
        dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ReadOnly = True
        dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Stocks is 0")
    Else
        dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ReadOnly = False
    End If
End Sub
```